# How to run parallel job in multiple instance in data stage?

Tags: datastage

I want to run parallel job in multiple session. Same parallel job for different different invocation id. For ex. I want to run one job for different users like a,b,c...at the same time. I know how to run it manually thru passing invocation id at right hand side while runing job.but while we are passing parameters thru unix in such conditions where I need to configure the parameters in a parallel to run in multiple session.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Pretty unclear - if I get it right you want to start a multi-instance job from command line - right? With dsjob?